# Class member function behaviour when calling const objects

Tags: c++, constants

I have the following piece of code

```
#include <string>

int Foo(const std::string& str){

    std::string::iterator start;

    start = str.begin();

    return 0;
}
```

When i compile it with GCC 4.7.3 i receive an error.As i suspect the error pops up because i am trying to assign a

```
std::string::const_iterator;
```

to an

```
std::string::iterator
```

So changing the line

```
std::string::iterator start;
```

To

```
std::string::const_iterator start;
```

Compiles it finely.

My question is how the std::string member function begin() recognises that the object it is being called by is const and so returns a const_iterator.

Making the question more general:
Can i change or somehow overload a class member function to act differently when being called by a const object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is how the std::string member function begin() recognises that the object it is being called by is const and so returns a const_iterator.

There are two overloads of `begin`:

```
iterator       begin();
const_iterator begin() const;
```

Which one gets chosen depends on the type of the implicit `this` parameter when you call a member function - in your case it's either `std::string&` or `const std::string&`.

n3337, 13.3.1

> 2 The set of candidate functions can contain both member and non-member functions to be resolved against
>   the same argument list. So that argument and parameter lists are comparable within this heterogeneous
>   set, **a member function is considered to have an extra parameter, called the implicit object parameter, which
>   represents the object for which the member function has been called.** For the purposes of overload resolution,
>   both static and non-static member functions have an implicit object parameter, but constructors do not.

Only `const` qualified member function can be called on a `const` qualified object parameter.

How does compiler know that `str` is const? Well, you told it in the declaration of `Foo`.

Comment: The implicit this parameter was what i was missing.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how the std::string member function begin() recognises
>   that the object it is being called by is const and so returns a
>   const_iterator.

The [`begin()` method has an overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/begin) where that is `const` qualified that returns a `const_iterator`. Being `const` qualified means that it is the one that is used when the object it is being called from is `const`

```
iterator begin();
const_iterator begin() const;  // This one
```

With `str` being `const`, the second one is called, therefore the object returned is a `const_iterator`, the you try to assign to an `iterator` which is invalid and thus the error.

---

> Can i change or somehow overload a class member function to act
>   differently when being called by a const object?

Use `auto`! Instead of doing

```
std::string::iterator start;

start = str.begin();
```

Do

```
auto start = str.begin();
```

With that, you are actually using the *exact type* of what is being returned by `begin()`.

However, you may be doing things the wrong way, as whether you need a const or non-const iterator depends on the task you want to achieve. As a general guideline, always use const iterators unless you intend to modify the elements inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler automatically selects a const member function if your object is const.

You will have to provide two member functions:

```
void someMethod();
void someMethod() const;
```